# Why is there no Local Windows Debugger in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, cocos2d-x

My friend has Local Windows debugger on his Visual Studio which I think enables him to run C++ files on his PC. That somehow is missing on mine. I only have 
-Remote Machine
-Windows Emulator that do not run

I want to run the Local Windows debugger to build for win32 exe files. What seems to be the problem? We're both using Visual Studios.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you're running cocos2d-x on Visual Studio and want to run it in  Local Windows debugger, you have to open it using:

<kbd>MyGame</kbd>-<kbd>proj.win32</kbd>-MyGame.sln

And there you have it:

[image]